# determinant of the symmetric matrix $8\times8$

Tags: matrices, determinant

How to compute the determinant of the following matrix:

$ \left( \begin{array}{cccccccc} 
2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 
\end{array}  \right)$

Comment: Find the eigenvalues.

Comment: Have you tried computing the same matrix of order 2, 3 and 4, guess a formula and try induction?

Answer (score 1):

you can write your matrix as $$I + uu^T, \det(I + uu^T) = n+1.$$ we have  $u = (1,1,1, \ldots, 1)$ and the eigenvalues of $uu^T$ are $n, 0, 0, \ldots , 0.$ that means the eigenvalues of $I + uu^T$ are $n+1, 1, 1, \cdots, 1.$  so the determinant is $n+1.$

Comment: Very neat idea!

Comment: @AdLibitum, thank you. these matrices are known as rank one perturbations.

Comment: You could also immediately tell that $\det(I+uu^T)=n+1$ because of [Sylvester's determinant theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_theorem) and because the determinant of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} n\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1+n\end{bmatrix}$ is *really* easy to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

Write this matrix as a linear combination of two matrices:

$Q$ is the $8\times 8$ matrix in which every entry is $1/8$.  Show that the rank of $Q$ is $1$.

$P=I-Q$, where  $I$ is the $8\times 8$ identity matrix.  Show that the rank of $P$ is $7$.

Show that $Q$ is the matrix of the orthogonal projection onto the space $A=\{ x(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)^\top : x\in\mathbb R\}$ and $P$ is the matrix of the complementary orthogonal projection onto the space $B=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_8)^\top : x_1+\cdots+x_8=0\}$.

It follows that there is an orthonormal basis in which $P$ and $Q$ are both diagonal matrices with no scalars on the diagonal except $0$ and $1$: One member of that basis spans the $1$-dimensional subspace $A$ above; the other seven space the $7$-dimensional orthogonal complement $B$.

It follows that $\det (aP+bQ) = a^7 b$.

You just need to find $a$ and $b$, and that's the easiest part of all this.

Answer (score 0):

There is another trick available here which works for any such $n \times n$ matrix). Call your matrix $A$. For $1 \leq i \leq n-1,$ let $v_{i}$ be the columnn vector with $1$ in entry $i, -1$ in entry $i+1$, and $0$ elsewhere. Then $Av_{i} = v_{i}$ for each $i$, and $\{v_{i}: 1 \leq i \leq n-1 \}$ is linearly independent. Hence $A$ has $n-1$ linearly independent eigenvectors with eigenvalue $1$, so $1$ occurs as an eigenvalue of $A$ with algebraic multiplicity at least $n-1.$ Since trace($A$) $=2n,$ the other eigenvalue of $A$ must be $n+1,$ and det($A$)$=n+1.$